# Perl array being modified by unknown source

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I believe I am encountering a bug, but wanted to be sure that I wasn't just missing  something. My intern is working on website that will have tests of a variable number of questions with a variable number of answers for associates to complete for training. We are storing the questions in a 2D array, containing the question ID, and the question text. We loop through that array to create divs for each question, hiding all but the first, and use that question ID to get the answers to that question in the loop.

What we are encountering though, is that when the `for` loop gets to the last index, an empty element is pushed onto `@questions`. This increases the result of `scalar @questions` by one, and this cycle repeats indefinitely. What we cannot figure out though is **what is causing an empty element to be pushed to @questions?**

```
my @questions;

my $getQuestion = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT ID, Question 
    FROM ACTestQuestions
    WHERE TestID = ?
");

$getQuestion->execute(1);

while(my @question = $getQuestion->fetchrow_array()){
    push(@questions, \@question);
}

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("
    SELECT ID, AnswerText, CorrectAnswer
    FROM ACTestAnswers
    WHERE QuestionID = ?
    ORDER BY SortOrder
");

# Irrelevant parts skipped

for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar @questions; $i++){
    my $qCount = 1;
    my $qID = $questions[$i][0];
    my $hideClass = "hide";

    if($i == 0){
        $hideClass = "";
    }
    print <<"END_HTML";
    <div id="question-$questions[$i][0]"  class="centered question-container $hideClass">
        <h1 class="text-center">Question &num;$qCount</h1>
        <h4 class="text-center" >$questions[$i][1]</h4></br>
            <form method="get">
                <table>                     
END_HTML

    if($sth->execute($questions[$i][0])){
        $num = 1;
        while(($ansID, $ansText, $correct) = $sth->fetchrow_array()){
            print <<"END_HTML";
            <tr>
            <td style="padding: 15px 30px"> 
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer" id="$ansID" value="$ansID" />
                    $num. $ansText
                </label>
            </td>
            </tr>
END_HTML
            $num++;
        }
    }

    print <<"END_HTML";
                </table>
                <div class="text-center" style="padding: 25px; font-weight: bold;">
                    $ans
                </div>
                <div class="tButton">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    <button type="button" id="prev" class="prev" onclick="prevQuestion($questions[$i-1][0])">&laquo; prev
                    <button type="button" id="next" class="next" onclick="nextQuestion($questions[$i+1][0])">next &raquo;
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
END_HTML
    $qCount++;
}
```

#### Update

Here is a dump of `@questions` before and after the loop. I used a hard coded `$i < 18` to get this result, but as is, it will go on until it runs out of memory.

```
[10/24/18 17:25:05] $VAR1 = [
          [
            9,
            'What are the key ingredients in the Original Killer Brownie&reg;?'
          ],
          [
            10,
            'Where do our Laura&#39;s Cookies come from?'
          ],
          [
            11,
            'How long is the shelf life on our artisan breads?'
          ],
          [
            12,
            'What happens to the bakery shrink (the items no longer fresh enough to sell)?'
          ],
          [
            13,
            'How many days a week are DLM artisan breads produced?'
          ],
          [
            14,
            'DLM artisan breads are produced in a ____ style oven.'
          ],
          [
            15,
            'How many items does Central Bakery produce for the stores?'
          ],
          [
            16,
            "TEST"
          ]
        ];
[10/24/18 17:25:05] $VAR1 = [
          [
            9,
            'What are the key ingredients in the Original Killer Brownie&reg;?'
          ],
          [
            10,
            'Where do our Laura&#39;s Cookies come from?'
          ],
          [
            11,
            'How long is the shelf life on our artisan breads?'
          ],
          [
            12,
            'What happens to the bakery shrink (the items no longer fresh enough to sell)?'
          ],
          [
            13,
            'How many days a week are DLM artisan breads produced?'
          ],
          [
            14,
            'DLM artisan breads are produced in a ____ style oven.'
          ],
          [
            15,
            'How many items does Central Bakery produce for the stores?'
          ],
          [
            16,
            "TEST"
          ],
          [],
          [],
          [],
          [],
          [],
          [],
          [],
          [],
          [],
          [],
          []
        ];
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Also, whenever I see stuff like *`# Irrelevant parts skipped`* I immediately want to know what was there because that's probably where the bug is hiding.

Comment: I understand your concern @melpomene, but I assure it truely is irrelevant. It is simply some JS to help with client-side validation for the test. I am trying to be minimal and relevant.

Comment: Be complete first. This code is not complete: It lacks `strict` and `warnings`, and `$dbh` is undefined.

Comment: Have you thought about using [selectrow_array](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectall_array) or a similar method instead of a manual loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<button type="button" id="next" class="next" onclick="nextQuestion($questions[$i+1][0])">next &raquo;
```

The expression `$questions[$i+1][0]` will [autovivify](https://perldoc.pl/perlglossary#autovivification) the element `$questions[$i+1]` into an array reference, since you accessed it like one. Thus `@questions` will then have an extra element. You can use the [autovivification](https://metacpan.org/pod/autovivification) pragma to prevent that from happening, or check that `$questions[$i+1]` is defined or if `$i < $#questions` before using it. `$#questions` is a shortcut for the last index of the array `@questions`. Note: you may have a similar issue with the prevQuestion line and index 0, though index -1 will just access the last element of the array.

The other angle to this problem is that your C-style for loop is depending on the size of `@questions` at every iteration. An alternative is to use a Perlish [foreach loop](https://perldoc.pl/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops).

```
foreach my $i (0..$#questions) {
  # everything else the same
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have never heard of this subject before, and I will definitely keep this in mind for the future.